# Vue: Group data by day, then by time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to group a list of events first by tay, and then by time. I'm able to get one layer of this, but I'm stuck on the second.

In the end, it should look something like this:

> **Friday**
>   8:00 - Event 1, Event 2, etc…
>   9:00 - Event 1, Event 2, etc…
>   …
>
> **Saturday**
>   8:00 - Event 1, Event 2, etc…
>   9:00 - Event 1, Event 2, etc…
>   …

Here's my code so far, which gives me the day-level groupings. I'm extremely new to this, so if there's an obviously better approach, I'm happy to explore it.

Here's a [CodePen version](https://codepen.io/freshyill/pen/jjqJQW). This does the day grouping, but not the time grouping.

I've tried several things. I understand that I probably need to do something similar to what I'm doing with the date, but I'm not sure how to create, loop through, and display arrays that don't exist yet.

```html
<div id="vue">
  <div v-for="events, day in groupedDays" class="day">
    <h2>{{ day == today ? 'Today' : day }}</h2>
    <div v-for="event, time in events">
      {{ event.date.toLocaleTimeString() }} - {{ event.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function groupBy(array, fn) {
  let result = {};
  array.forEach(item => {
    let key = fn(item);

    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = [];
    }
    result[key].push(item);
  });
  return result;
}

let conferenceDays = [];

for (let [key, session] of Object.entries(sessions)) {
  // console.log(session.Start);
  conferenceDays.push({
    date: new Date(session.Start),
    title: session.Title
  });
}

new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data() {
    return {
      conferenceDays,
      today: new Date().toDateString()
    };
  },
  computed: {
    groupedDays() {
      return groupBy(this.conferenceDays, day => day.date.toDateString());
    }
  }
});
```

I know somebody will very helpfully label this as a duplicate of some vaguely similar question, so please know that I *did* search extensively, and I didn't locate any questions with *two* levels of groupings. Again, I'm open to different solutions if I'm approaching this in a bad way.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the following:

In the `groupBy` function, first sort the array in ascending order and then transform each day into an **object** whose **keys** and **values** would be the **starting hours** and **the conferences** that start at that time, respectively.

```
function groupBy(array) {
  return array 
    .sort((c1, c2) => c1.date.getTime() - c2.date.getTime())
    .reduce((acc, crt) => {
    const k = crt.date.toDateString();
    const hr = crt.date.toLocaleTimeString();

    if (!acc[k]) {
      acc[k] = {};
    }

    acc[k][hr] = acc[k][hr] || [];
    acc[k][hr].push(crt.title);

    return acc;
  }, {})
}
```

As a result, your html would look like this:

```html
<div v-for="events, day in groupedDays" class="day">
    <h2>{{ day == today ? 'Today' : day }}</h2>
    <div v-for="conferences, time in events">
      {{ time }} - {{ conferences.join(', ') }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here's the CodePen](https://codepen.io/Andreigtj/pen/qzNrQw?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0):

for the data wrangling you propose you need to proceed in three steps:

<sup>i will use `lodash` as my data-plumbing library of choice, you dont have to use it</sup>

group all the conferences per day (that you have achieved)

```
function groupAllConferencesByDay(all) {
    return _(all)
           .groupBy(conference => conference.date.toDateString())
           .mapValues(groupDaysConferencesByTime) // <---
           .value()
}
```

for each day, group this days conferences by their timeslot

```
function groupDaysConferencesByTime(day) {
    return _(day)
           .groupBy(conference=>conference.date.toLocaleTimeString())
           .mapValues(concatTitleOfSimultaniousConferences)
           .value()
}
```

for each timeslot get the conferences titles and join them with commas

```
function concatTitleOfSimultaniousConferences(timeslot) {
  return _.map(timeslot, conference => conference.title )
          .join(", ")
         // dont need .value() here as we are using _.map(X, Y)
         // as opposite to _(X).map(Y)
}
```

you can then present the data to user like

```
<div id="vue">
  <div v-for="events, day in groupedDays" class="day">
    <h2>{{ day == today ? 'Today' : day }}</h2>
    <div v-for="conferences, time in events">
      {{ time }} - {{ conferences }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[pen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMemLd)